# Medium editor does not take more than one space is anyone know how to do that?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, web-deployment, medium-editor

I was just playing with the [medium](https://medium.com/new-story) editor I found something special. while writing if you try to hit space more than once it does not work means the editor does not accept more than one space. How cool it is.

[image]

it will be cool if we implement this in **textareas** or **contenteditable** to restrict the user from entering lots of spaces.

#### if somebody knows how to do it please share it with me.

## Update

```
<h2 contenteditable="true">Write here</h2>
```

how do i restrict user from hiting more than one space.

Comment: @Teemu how to do it with javascript.

Comment: @Teemu There is a use case. i updated my question.

Comment: Hmm ... I somehow managed to miss the actual question. `contenteditable` API is crappy in all browsers, it creates `&nbsp;` entities when you enter multiple spaces, in plain text they're allowed anyway. You've to capture the input (key strokes, pasting, dropping) and remove the extra spacing. The task is not trivial, and needs a different approach for textareas and contenteditables, An attempt to solve the problem is expected.

Comment: @Teemu i tried to solve with the events and it is working but not exactly. can I show you a codepen example?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Actually, the task is [quite trivial](https://jsfiddle.net/ak4jqcp6/) with textareas and input elements, but contenteditables are a nightmare, especially when trying to implement something working cross-browser.

Comment: @Teemu just give me a little time. i want to refactor it so you can understand clearly how i am solving.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with a textarea. You won't be able to type in more than one space when typing in characters into this textarea. Is this what you were looking for?:

```js
function trimSpaces(event){
   var content = $('#sampleText').val();
   //If you need to trim all white spaces and replace with single space
   //content = content.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');

   $('#sampleText').val("");
   content = content.replace(/  +/g, ' ');
   $('#sampleText').val(content);
}

function validate(event){
    // Donot add the character keyed into textbox before validation
 event.preventDefault();
 var content = $('#sampleText').val();
    //which is supported by FF and keyCode by other browsers. 
 var x = event.which || event.keyCode;
 
 if(x==32){
   if( content[content.length -1] ==" "){
         // Do nothing if previous character was a space
   }else{
        // Add the character into the text area if its not a space
  content+=String.fromCharCode(x);
  $('#sampleText').val(content);
   }
 }else{
        // add any characters keyed in to the text area if its not a space.
  content+=String.fromCharCode(x);
  $('#sampleText').val(content);
 } 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <textarea name="sampleText" id="sampleText" maxlength="200" onkeypress="validate(event)" onkeyup="trimSpaces(event)"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can still paste and drop values with multiple spaces to the textarea. And both, `event.which` and `event.keyCode` are deprecated.

Comment: @Teemu - the paste with multiple spaces can be taken care using regex.  event.which and event.keycode are so far the best ones we can use to get the desired output. Please do let me know if there is another way. Modified the code to take care of the pasting scenario on key up.

Comment: @thommu there is a catch. cursor not able to go back. and what if I want to add space between the previous word

Comment: @thommu Please take a look at the fiddle I've linked in the comment thread of the question. Also, there are new event properties: `event.key` and `event.code`, these properties will replace the old properties in the near(?) future, and the deprecated properties will be dropped all together. See ex. [KeyboardEvent.which](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which).